# Algorithm Check for Switch Program

Tags: algorithm, math, binary, logic, brute-force

I have 4 switches that are randomly generated at run time. Ex:

Switch1: 1 0 0 0
Switch2: 0 1 0 0
Switch3: 0 0 1 0 
Switch4: 0 0 0 1

When the switch is generated, the column for the switch number needs to be 1, but all other columns are randomly assigned (1 or 0).

A main switch performs an XOR operation on a switch that the user selects. The main switch starts at 0 0 0 0.

When the user selects a switch ( s1,s2,s3,s4 ) it is "XOR"ed to the current main switch.

Real Case:
S1: 1 1 0 0
S2: 0 1 1 0
S3: 0 0 1 0
S4: 1 0 0 1
START: 0 0 0 0
AND S1:1 1 0 0
AND S3:1 1 1 0

The objective is to get the main switch to 1 1 1 1.

When the four switches are created at run-time, I need to ensure that the puzzle is solvable. Any suggestions on how I can compare the four switches to determine if there is a combination to achieve a winning result of 1 1 1 1.

**UPDATE------------**
Note:
0 and 0 = 0
1 and 1 = 0
0 and 1 = 1

Comment: the operation is OR, not AND

Answer (score 1):

> The main switch starts at 0 0 0 0.
>
> When the user selects a switch ( s1,s2,s3,s4 ) it is ANDED to the current main switch.

If you start with `0000` and the only operation available is AND, you cannot get anything except `0000` as a result:  `0 & 1 = 0`, not `0 & 1 = 1`.

Based on the example in your Real Case, it appears that you are performing an OR operation.  If this is the case then any puzzle is solvable since

> the column for the switch number needs to be 1

If you OR each switch with the original `0000` main switch you will always get `1111`.  You may get it before OR'ing with all four switches, based on the other randomly assigned bits, but you are guaranteed to get `1111` if you OR each switch with the original main switch.

Comment: There are cases where this is not solvable, and yes they are 'OR' operations, I have corrected the question.

Comment: I must be missing something then.  Tell me where my understanding is incorrect.  Your main switch (MS) starts at 0000.  (s1, s2, s3, s4) start at (1xxx, x1xx, xx1x, xxx1) respectively, where 'x' denotes unknown, could be 0 or 1, I'll argue that we don't care.  If you OR MS with s1 you get 1xxx.  If you OR this with s2 you get 11xx.  If you OR this with s3 and then s4 you get 1111.  What am I missing?

Comment: You are completely correct. I now realize why I was confused about the original question being AND or OR logic. Please see the update @huck_cussler

Comment: Cool.  That makes this puzzle a lot more interesting.  For what it's worth, that operation is usually referred to as XOR, or 'exclusive or', and is true only when exactly one of the operands is true.  Put another way, it is true when A or B is true but not both.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved pretty easy, assuming you represent the switches as `Integer`:

```
public boolean isSolvable(Switch[] switches){
    int[] tmp = new int[SWITCH.COUNT];

    //generate an integer with all 1s of all switches
    for(Switch sw : switches)
        for(int i = 0 ; i < tmp.length ; i++)
            tmp[i] |= sw.get(i);

    //check if all bits that are part of the switches are 1
    for(int i : tmp)
        if(i == 0)
            return false;//this bit is 0 -> can't be set to 1 by combining switches

    //all bits can be set to 1 by combining switches
    return true;
}
```

Hope this java-code helps. I can explain further if necassary. Though the constraint that switch `i` has column `i` set to 1 ensures that a solution exists, if the number of switches is atleast equal to the number of columns in each switch.

Comment: The source is in Java. The switches are an instance of a class with 4 integer properties for each position. ( 1 though 4). Could you modify your answer for this situation? Much Appreciated!! @Paul